# Create a test for a void extension method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, extension-methods, xunit

How exactly do you create a test for a void extension method? I'm using XUnit.

I have a extension method that throws an exception if something is true.

```
public static void IsClosed(this List<Contract> contracts)
{
    if (contracts.Any(x => x.Status == Status.Closed) throw new IsClosedException();
}
```

In the test I cannot ceate for example :

```
var sut = contracts.IsClosed();
```

Do I need to mock a list of contracts?

```
var contracts = Mock<List<Contract>>());
```

But what then?

```
contracts.Setup...?
```

Or

```
contracts.Invoke...?
```

Comment: "In the test I cannot ceate for example" Eeeehm, why you can't do that? Should work IMHO. Just create some dummy-list for your test and call the extension-method.

Comment: _"Do I need to mock a list of contracts?"_ - No, just create a list that should make the extension method behave as you expect.

Comment: Btw: This makes me suspicious of a "Misuse Exceptions for control flow"-Antipattern going on here...

Comment: @Fildor I'm using 'Exceptions for control flow' yes ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[Fact]
void ShouldThrowIsClosedException()
{
    // Just create a list that you expect to trigger the Exception ...
    List<Contract> contracts = new() { new() {Status == Status.Closed}};
   
    Assert.Throws<IsClosedException>(contracts.IsClosed);
}
```

should do the trick.

As remarked by Jon Skeet: A complementary test should be added, too. (I.e. where the exception is *not* thrown.)

If you want to get really fancy, you can also test different lists:

```
[Theory]
[ClassData(typeof(ShouldThrowIsClosedExceptionTestData))]
void ShouldThrowIsClosedException(List<Contract> contracts)
{
    Assert.Throws<IsClosedException>(contracts.IsClosed);
}

// ...
public class ShouldThrowIsClosedExceptionTestData 
    : TheroyData<List<Contract>>
{
    public ShouldThrowIsClosedExceptionTestData()
    {
// Single entry
        Add (new List<Contract>() { new() {Status == Status.Closed}});
// Multiple entries
        Add (new List<Contract>() { new() {Status == Status.Closed}, new() {Status == Status.Closed}});
// Mixed entries
        Add (new List<Contract>() { new() {Status == Status.Closed}, new() {Status == Status.Open}});
        Add (new List<Contract>() { new() {Status == Status.Open}, new() {Status == Status.Closed}});
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason not to use `Assert.Throws` instead?

Comment: (And obviously there should be a corresponding test that *doesn't* throw...)

Comment: @JonSkeet My bad ... we are using FluentAssertions, so I simply forgot about that one. Edited according to your remarks. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks guys, indeed your solution works. After consulting the Fluent Assertions documentation, I found out that this also works :
'Action action = () => contracts.IsClosed();' and then 'action.Should().Throw<IsClosedException>();'.

Comment: Yes, I intentionally did not use FluentAssertions in the answer to be useful for a wider audience. But of course, that would be the equivalent. Also the answer focuses on the problem of the question, which is how to provide input data.